# Please fix the version conflict with updating my gradle with Google with Firebase

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

After updating my google play services to **Firebase** I'm getting this error. I'm not sure why this is happening as it was working fine before.

This message keeps appearing:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the Google services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

here is my **build.gradle** file

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 24
  buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.transcendencetech.juliospizzaprototype"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'



  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.4'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'`, is that version `9.0.0` as stated in the error?

Comment: Yes, sir. It comes up with that exact error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase

In your app/build.gradle file, within:

```
dependencies {
  ...
}
```

Move this line: `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to the outside.

The docs instruct you to put that line at the very bottom.

Comment: Please rate my question

Answer (score 1):

As per the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase) provided in the answer above, you must add the "apply plugin line" at the bottom of your .gradle file but of course outside dependencies.

> dependencies {  ...
>
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
>
> Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have the latest
> Google Repository in the Android SDK manager }
>
> // ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
>
> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'